# Content in Lightbox dialog

Tags: 6, hooks, forms

Is this possible to pass some content (cck fields values) to Lightbox dialog when image belongs to the same content type is opened?

Answer (score 1):

Lightbox is specifically design to preview images. For General purpose overlay preview for images, videos, iframe and any custom html/text I recommend to use [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). [Fancybox module](http://drupal.org/project/fancybox) is available for integration in druapl.

```
$.fancybox("Your HTML");
```

Comment: Thanks. What about image attributes: title, alt, is this possible to output them on dialog?

Comment: yes title works as caption on the dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) module which allows to load inline content and url content.

> Colorbox is a light-weight, customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery 1.3 through 1.6. This module allows for integration of Colorbox into Drupal.
>
> Images, iframed or inline content etc. can be displayed in a overlay above the current page.